# How do I select previous siblings before specific class?

Tags: javascript, css

My react app is creating a list of steps:

```
let steps = this.props.formSteps.map((step, i) => {
            let stepNum = i +1;
            return (
                <li className={ i == this.props.currentStepsIndex ? "steps__step active" : "steps__step"} key={"li-"+i}
                 onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, i)}>
                  {step.name}
                </li>
            );
})
return(
  <div className="steps-container">
    <ul className="steps">
      {steps}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

With 3 steps, the generated html looks something like this:

```
<ul class="steps">
  <li class="steps__step">Step 1</li>
  <li class="steps__step">Step 2</li>
  <li class="steps__step active">Step 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to select all the previous li steps before the active class and set the background to like green or something.

How do I accomplish this using css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something like this. You invert the logic and you select all next sibling to remove the background:

```css
.steps__step {
 background:green;
}

.active,
.active ~ .steps__step {
 background:none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="steps">
  <li class="steps__step">Step 1</li>
  <li class="steps__step">Step 2</li>
  <li class="steps__step active">Step 3</li>
  <li class="steps__step">Step 4</li>
  <li class="steps__step">Step 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This method works great! Better this than putting in more logic with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any css selectors for sibling elements that come before a specific sibling. However, in your specific case you might get the desired result by selecting the elements without the "active" class.

Something like:

```
.steps__step:not(.active) {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: See the more complete answer from @Temani Afif to style only elements that come before the "active" element.

Answer (score 0):

You might use this syntax:

```css
.steps__step:not(.active, .active ~ .steps__step) {
 background:green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="steps">
  <li class="steps__step">Step 1</li>
  <li class="steps__step">Step 2</li>
  <li class="steps__step active">Step 3</li>
  <li class="steps__step">Step 4</li>
  <li class="steps__step">Step 5</li>
</ul>
```