# How do I select all siblings before an element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping, node-html-parser

I'm using `node-html-parser` to parse a document. The structure is below:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div
    style="
      margin-top: 20px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      font-family: PingFangSC;
    "
  >
    DIVIDER LOLZ
  </div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

I want to get all the elements before the divider, i.e., the first `.item` in the document.

Note: this is not a duplicate of [How do I select previous siblings before specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957261/how-do-i-select-previous-siblings-before-specific-class), which only styles the elements.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(CSS-selector)` gets all of the elements the CSS selector selects. So yes, it could be a duplicate...

Comment: @HereticMonkey But none of the answers have a selector that does this.

Comment: @Barmar Did I say it was a duplicate? No, there are no close votes. I said it *could be* a duplicate. Just refuting the idea that, just because a question asks about selecting elements for styling doesn't mean you couldn't use the answers for selecting elements for anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked your code a bit, but the idea remains the same.
You might use selector `.item:not(.divider ~ .item)`

```js
const items_before_divider = document.querySelectorAll('.content > .item:not(.divider~.item)');

items_before_divider.forEach(item => console.log(item.outerHTML))
```

```css
.divider {margin-top: 20px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      font-family: PingFangSC}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">0</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="divider">DIVIDER LOLZ</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if I can't update the class name?

Comment: tried `.content > .item:not(div:not(item)~.item)` and it worked!